# Unordered map size in bytes

Tags: c++

I have an unorderedmap and I want to measure how much memory it consumes in my program.
The unorderedmap is like this:

```
Key =>  int, int

Value => int, bool
```

I want to find out the size of the map in bytes.
I am making use of .size() function to find out the number of elements in the container (number of rows in map). I am calculating the size of the unorderedmap like this

```
unordermap.size()  * (2bytes+2bytes+2bytes+1byte)
```

Is this the right way to estimate the memory consumed by unordermap in bytes?

Comment: Not sure if c++ has this, but there should be something like object overhead which is the size an object by default occupies in memory. This should be accounted for as well. C++ has the `sizeof` operator which you can also use to find out if you are correct

Comment: @Smac89 the `sizeof` operator is the static size. It does not take into account the size of the elements in a collection.

Comment: That's true, but at least using `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(bool)` instead of `2` and `1` respectively can only improve things

Comment: Use a custom allocator which tracks the memory usage and specify it when you declare the map.

Comment: @MartinJ Actually I am not doing these calculations in a program. Just calculating map.size() in a program. Once I get this value I multiply it with 7 bytes to get the total size of map in bytes. Will this affect my estimated memory usage?

Comment: Well, the actual size of an `int` is usually 4 bytes, and `bool` is commonly 1, 2 or 4 bytes...

Comment: @MartinJ Thanks.I calculated int and bool size using sizeof() and it gives 4 bytes for int and 1 byte for bool.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious can you please give an example how to create custom allocator and then determining memory usage from that.

Answer (score 0):

Memory footprint of data structure is size on stack + size in free store. You can redefine operator new/delete to add allocated size accounting and then do simple arithmetics. You also might need to do it for malloc/free.